# Error Debug Failure. False expression: import= for internal module references should be handled in an earlier transformer

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I'm getting the following error during nest build script:
`Error  Debug Failure. False expression: import= for internal module references should be handled in an earlier transformer.`
I am not able to understand what it indicate. Want succesfull nest build phase

Comment: Can you provide code/ additional output?

Comment: @VincentMenzel this is the only error I'm getting.
> nest build
 Error  Debug Failure. False expression: import= for internal module references should be handled in an earlier transformer.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, wondering if it has something to do with nest dependency

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VincentMenzel I fixed the issue by changing my typescript version, mine was  "typescript": "^5.0.2", i changed to  "typescript": "^4.3.5"

Answer (score 7):

`Typescript` v5.2 contains a "small" breaking change (see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-2/#modules-always-emits-as-namespace) which I suspect triggers the problem in `webpack`.

> TypeScript 5.2 will always emit the namespace keyword when generating declaration files. So code like the following:
>
> ```
> module foo {
>     export function f() {} 
> }
> ```
>
> will result in the following declaration file:
>
> ```
> declare namespace foo {
>     function f(): void; 
> }
> ```
>
> While this may be incompatible with much much older versions of TypeScript, we believe the impact should be limited.

Of course, this *should* have meant that `5.2` was actually `6.0` if they were truly being `semver` compliant.

I have temporarily pinned my `typescript` at `v5.1.6` and all seems well with `webpack 5.88.2` (which is a dependency of my current version of `nestjs`